# Cómo remplazar variables en mi script de descarga

Tags: cmd, powershell, appveyor

Trataba de portar [mi script](https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester/blob/master/.travis.yml) de [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) al appveyor y no hallo la manera de **remplazar los valores en mi script con el valor de la variable de sistema**.

Este es mi script actual:

```
before_build:
  - cd client-idea
  - if not exist lib mkdir lib
  - cd lib
  - ECHO certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f \"https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/$(VERSION)/ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip\" ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
  - certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/$(VERSION)/ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip" ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
  - jar xf ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
  - cd ..
  - cd..
```

La variable de sistema `VERSION` la agregué desde el panel de configuración, su valor es `2018.2.7` y la sintaxis de interpolación la saqué [de una pregunta](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/256-how-to-interpolate-strings-in-appveyoryml).

Al correr obtengo lo siguiente en consola:

```
cd client-idea
if not exist lib mkdir lib
cd lib
ECHO certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f \"https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/$(VERSION)/ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip\" ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f \"https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/$(VERSION)/ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip\" ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/$(VERSION)/ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip" ideaIC-$(VERSION).zip
```

> ****  Online  ****   0000  ...   0152 CertUtil: -URLCache command FAILED: 0x80190194 (-2145844844 HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND) CertUtil: Not
>   found (404). Command exited with code -2145844844

Comment: No conozco mucho pero veo en el código, que la primera línea de `certutil` tiene una barra invertida `-f \"`, pero en la segunda línea no la tiene. ¿Eso debería ser así? Además una tiene `ECHO` y otra no.

Comment: @ArtEze el escapar una `"` no debería de influir en la impresión de `$(VERSION)`

Comment: ¿Es posible evitar el uso de comillas para un HTTP? Nuevamente insisto, quizás se solucione quitando las comillas o no escapándolas. En batch también puedes probar usar variables con porcentajes. `%vari%` en vez del signo pesos (`$`).

Comment: es irrelevante, ya que como verás estoy tratando de imprimir la variable dentro y fuera del string

Comment: @ArtEze respecto a usar `%` https://ci.appveyor.com/project/javatlacati/regextester